# PrintWriter will not write CSV S3

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to use **PrintWriter** but I am getting an error, and I am not able to figure out what am I am missing here, complains about FileNotFoundException when trying to create a new file in a S3 bucket.
code as below,

Error **java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3a:/tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv (No such file or directory)**

```
val inputFile = "s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Cleartablet.csv" 
val outputFile = "s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv"
val fileSystem = getFileSystem(inputFile)
val inputData = readCSVFileLines(fileSystem, inputFile, skipHeader = true).toSeq
val filtinp = inputData.filter(x => x.nonEmpty)
  .map(x => x.split(","))
  .map(x => Revenue(x(6), x(5), x(0), x(8).toDouble))

val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFile)) // Create output writer
writer.write("Date,customer,number,Credit,Average Credit/SKU\n") // Header for output CSV file
filtinp.foreach(x => {
val (com1, avg1) = com1Average(filtermp, x)
val (com2, avg2) = com2Average(filtermp, x)
  })

  writer.write(s"${x.day},${x.customer},${x.number},${x.credit},${avgcredit1},${avgcredit2}\n") // Write row to output csv file
  })
  writer.close() // close the writer`
```

Comment: Where does the exception happen?  At line: val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFile)) or Line writer.write() ? put them in try/catch blocks to isolate.

Comment: Presumably the `raidnd` directory actually exists otherwise the code that reads the CSV would fail.  So do you have write access to that bucket?

Comment: if try using dataframe write I got this error..

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 50, 10.239.78.116, executor 0): java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: tfstest/0/outputFile/_started_7476690454845668203: regular upload on tfstest/0/outputFile/_started_7476690454845668203: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied; request: PUT https://tfs-databricks-sys-test.s3.amazonaws.com tfstest/0/outputFile/_started_7476690454845668203 {}

Comment: but the path/url AWS resource is not the one I'm using, so not sure why shows that in the log error